# Can't find any file placeholder for the GIT log pretty format

Tags: git

I'm trying to export a GIT log in pretty format containing both author, commit message AND the files that were changed in that commit. I've been looking at the git log documentation here

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

But I can't find any placeholder useful to give me a list of files changed in a certain commit.

There is, for example, the `--full-diff` option, but I don't know how to connect that with pretty format.

Comment: `--format` presents information from the commit header. For the list of files of the diff there are no placeholders, they are always come after the commit header.

Comment: @phd So what you're saying is that the log command only deals with the headers, not the actual content?

Comment: `git log` deals with everything but it has its own ways of displaying information. `--format` doesn't have placeholders for "content". The "content" can be displayed but not using `--format`. There are `--name-*` options and `--diff-*` options but their output is always come after the commit.